# Boot with problem Ubuntu 20.04.01

Tags: boot

Every time I turn on the notebook, the initialization is like this

https://freeimage.host/i/Fwx80u

passing several texts and it takes at least 3-5 minutes before the login screen appears even though it is an HD SSD. (even selecting at installation to automatically login)

I have already done a complete reinstallation excluding all partitions (including EFI) and redoing but the problem persists.

The most curious thing is that if during this screen I force the shutdown (holding the power for 4 seconds) the next time I turn on, the GRUB menu will be shown, and when I press ENTER, everything will work normally and will start in seconds even with automatic login

How fix it ?

Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: I guess you should take a look at the messages to see if it's stuck on something.  "3-5 minutes" occasionally is ok since it has to check the HDD but that's very rare.  I guess it's loading something that's taking a while.  For example, connecting to network-based storage that isn't available (i.e., so it tries for a very long time) or something.  Try to look for that...  As for forcing the shutdown while it's booting...I suggest you don't do that.  It's not good for the system and you **do** raise an interesting point that's worth sharing, please don't do that any more!  :-)

Comment: My installation is brand new. The problem even occurs at boot immediately after installation